# Nebular 5.0.0 nb-select - dont work in editing register

Tags: nebular, ngx-admin

Please, help-me

I'am using a Nebular 5.0.0 + Angular FormGroup and when I select a register from a list for edit, nb-select do not has been updated.

My Form:

[image]

My .ts file:

[image]

My result Form:

[image]

All fields of FormGroup is updated nice, but nb-select in form do not refresh.

Can someone help me undestand what is missing ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

your code is good but seems ddlSis is not available at that moment so 
try below steps

1) in `ngOnInit` define formControls without value

2) load ddlSis data

3) pdfForm.pathcValues Or pdfForm.setValue  of form controls

Hope this helps

For a quick try [ to know the exactly issue ]

define in ts  `ddlSis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];`

HTML

```
 <nb-select placeholder="Select Showcase" selected="prfForm.controls.sis_id.value" formControlName="sis_id">
    <nb-option *ngFor="let item of ddlSis" value={{item}}>item</nb-option>
</nb-select>
```

This will work as ddlSis data is already available

Comment: Hi Neha, thanks for reponse.

The ddlSis was been populated. 

if (result.sis) {
      for (let i = 0; i < result.sis.length; i++) {
        this.ddlSis.push({ value: result.sis[i]['sis_id'], text: result.sis[i]['sis_sistema'] });
      }
    }

the problem is that when I get any record for editing, nb-select is not setting value got from register. The formcontrol was, but without any effect in the component.

Comment: Same problem here... When I add formControlName, setting don't work.